# Can't create events on iPhone 6 calendar

Tags: calendar, iphone

The calendar + icon to add an event doesn't seem to be working - it's grey in colour and when I try to tap it, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try going to Settings > iCloud. Switch off Calendars, wait a min, switch on. Sometimes it seems it needs a push.

Comment: Glad it worked - let me push it as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes all it needs is a push.

Go to Settings > iCloud

Switch off Calendars. Wait a minute…
Switch it back on.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use iCloud and stay signed out of it, go to Settings → iCloud → Calendar and toggle to turn off Calendar.

And then sign back out and your `+` symbol should be back to red and ready to make events.

If you use iCloud and are signed in: just toggle off and on to kind of reset it or Toggle off, sign out of iCloud, sign back in and toggle on.